# jQuery add the value of 2 input text then sum it with total

Tags: jquery

oh god i dont know what to do here please help me...

i have this html code

```
<div id="project_math">
<form method="post">
 Quantity : <input type="text" name="quatity" value="1" />
 Amount : <input type="text" name="amounty" value="20" />
 <span id="total">20</span>
</form>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    /* COMPUTATION */
    $('input[name=quantity_e]').keyup(function(){

        var sum = $('input[name=amt_e]').val();

        sum *= $('input[name=quantity_e]').val();
        $("#total").text($(this).val());

    });
});
```

what im trying to do is that when i `keyup` and input value like 2 or 10 it will times the value of it to the amount value so if i `keyup` 2 then the amount value is 20 the total should be 40.

is my jQuery wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`val` return a string. So you must convert it into a number. You can use `parseInt`.

```
var sum = parseInt($('input[name=amt_e]').val(), 10);
sum *= parseInt($('input[name=quantity_e]').val(), 10);
$("#total").text(sum);
```

The names you use in your javascript are not the same in your html. But it's maybe just your example.

Comment: thank you thank you so much for the that. im learning thumbs up

Comment: @user1538668 `$('input[name=total]').val(sum);` will place the value of sum in the hidden input named total. To ensure this works, you can open the console in your browser and type `$('input[name=total]').val();` and it should return you your number.

Answer (score 2):

Try `parseInt` for that:

```
    var sum = parseInt($('input[name=amt_e]').val());
    sum *= parseInt($('input[name=quantity_e]').val());
```

It will, of course, fail if the value is not an integer.

Answer (score 2):

Well, your selectors are wrong and `val` returns a string, you should first convert the string to a number.

```
$('input[name=quatity]').keyup(function(){
    var sum = parseInt(this.value, 10)
    sum *= parseInt($('input[name=amounty]').val(), 10);
    $("#total").text(sum);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

use this:

```
/* COMPUTATION */
$('input[name=quatity]').keyup(function(){

    var sum = parseInt($('input[name=amounty]').val());

    sum += parseInt($('input[name=quatity]').val());
    $("#total").text(sum);

});​
```

Try this on fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/XwjKN/

Answer (score 1):

**val()** returns string, so convert to int value using **[parseInt](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp) with 10 radix**, as default is 8

```
var total= parseInt($('input[name=amt_e]').val(), 10);
total*= parseInt($('input[name=quantity_e]').val(), 10);
$("#total").text(total);
```

Answer (score 0):

Above solution gives NaN if any text box is empty. please try this it will give 0.

var v1=0;
    var v2=0;

```
if(!isNaN(parseInt($('input[name=amounty]').val()))){ v1 = parseInt($('input[name=amounty]').val()); }
if(!isNaN(parseInt($('input[name=quatity]').val()))){ v2 = parseInt($('input[name=quatity]').val()); }


sum = v1 * v2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

```
var item1 = parseInt($('input[name=amounty]').val(), 10);
var item2 = parseInt($('input[name=quantity]').val(), 10);
if(item1 !== NaN && item2 !== NaN) {  //This is a check to make sure the values are numbers
    var product = item1 * item2;
    $('#total').text(product);
    $('input[name=total]).val(product);    //This will put the value in the hidden input field
}
```

This solution won't attempt to compute if the values are not both numbers.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

lot of corrections in INPUT field names:

1. Quantity is the actual input field name you might have wished, but it is not used correctly in both HTML and Jquery.
2. span displaying total value does not update with SUM you are calculating instead it always get updated with quantity value.

Find the corrected HTML:

```
<div id="project_math">
<form method="post">
 Quantity : <input type="text" name="quantity" value="1" />
 Amount : <input type="text" name="amounty" value="20" />
 <span id="total">20</span>
</form>
</div>​
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    /* COMPUTATION */
    $('input[name=quantity]').keyup(function(){

        console.log('fired');
        var sum = $('input[name=amounty]').val();

        sum *= $('input[name=quantity]').val();
        $("#total").text(sum );

    });
});​
```